# Finding unique elements of a column. TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'

Tags: python, numpy

"12" being the column name.In the syntax, it is supposed to be an array. How do I convert '12' to one in the given scenario.

```
print(np.unique(data_csv['12']))

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-61-ff7ee2ed6695> in <module>
      1 import numpy as np
----> 2 print(np.unique(data_csv['12']))

<__array_function__ internals> in unique(*args, **kwargs)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\arraysetops.py in unique(ar, return_index, return_inverse, return_counts, axis)
    261     ar = np.asanyarray(ar)
    262     if axis is None:
--> 263         ret = _unique1d(ar, return_index, return_inverse, return_counts)
    264         return _unpack_tuple(ret)
    265 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\arraysetops.py in _unique1d(ar, return_index, return_inverse, return_counts)
    309         aux = ar[perm]
    310     else:
--> 311         ar.sort()
    312         aux = ar
    313     mask = np.empty(aux.shape, dtype=np.bool_)

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'
```

Comment: seems your column has mismatching types, what is the type of `data_csv['12']`? if it is a pandas dataframe column do `np.unique(data_csv['12'].astype(float))`

Comment: dtype of the column '12' is object.

Comment: Please provide us with more detail and a minimal reproducible example. Specially what is in `data_csv['12']`?

Answer (score 1):

A possible cause of your error is that:

- You have read *data_csv* from a text file, calling e.g. *pd.read.csv*,
- Most values in *'12'* column in the source file contain strings convertible
  to numbers (e.g. *float*).
- But at least one cell contains a **non-convertible** string.
- So the type of this column, after reading, is *object*.

An example of the source content:

```
Name,12
a,3.0
b,4.1
c,2.0
a,3.0
b,1.0
c,2xx
```

So far each element in *'12'* column is a **string** and when you run:

```
np.unique(data_csv['12'])
```

you get a proper result:

```
array(['1.0', '2.0', '2xx', '3.0', '4.1'], dtype=object)
```

Now, to recreate your error, assign a *float* value to any cell in
this column, e.g.:

```
data_csv.iloc[0,1] = 3.0
```

The printed content of your DataFrame looks just the same, but when you
attempt to run `np.unique(data_csv['12'])` you will get the *TypeError*
exception.

The reason is that *Numpy* was written to operate on columns (or arrays) of
a **single** type (e.g. either *string* or *float*) but not both of them
intermixed.

One of possible solutions is to run the *pandasonic* implementation of
this function:

```
pd.unique(data_csv['12'])
```

which returns:

```
array([3.0, '4.1', '2.0', '3.0', '1.0', '2xx'], dtype=object)
```

Note that the result contains both **float 3.0** and **string 3.0**,
as they are of different types.

One of comments to your post suggest to run `np.unique(data_csv['12'].astype(float))`.
I tried it and got the same error. No surprise. As one of cells contains
a non-convertible string, this method actually changes nothing.

But if you convert each element to a **string** and then attempt to get
unique values:

```
np.unique(data_csv['12'].astype(str))
```

The result is:

```
array(['1.0', '2.0', '2xx', '3.0', '4.1'], dtype=object)
```

The above code raised no exception, because any *float* is convertible to string.

Consider also another solution: Your column of interest should probably
contain only *float*s and you should rather:

- find elements not convertible to *float*,
- replace them with either *NaN* or any other value of choice.